# Suppress internal WLAN interface on startup in Kali

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

If I need to suppress my WLAN interface from probing and being probed whenever I start up Kali, what is the right way to keep wlan0 down on startup.

I tried inserting a bash script below to the file `/etc/crontab`, but it is not working (wlan0 is still on automatically on startup and even connect to a Wifi).

```
#! /bin/sh

service NetworkManager stop
airmon-ng check kill
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this with init.d and rc.d

1. `sudo nano ~/etc/init.d/wlan0-down`
2. put this in it

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   ifconfig wlan0 down
   exit 0
   ```
3. `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/wlan0-down`
4. `sudo update-rc.d wlan0-down defaults`

That should shutdown wlan0 (or whatever you replace that with) at startup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it does not seem to work. The wlan0 is still up at startup and even auto-connect to a Wifi AP nearby.